# How to do nginx request monitoring

Tags: nginx, monitoring, nagios

I have gone through some tools like nagios, collectd but they din't find best as we need to monitor no_of_req/sec for each virtual host with all response status, with response time also.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Using `ELK Stack`:

Separate access logs for each server block for better visibility or you can separate charts via URLs.

Then Use `ELK stack`:

1. Feed the logs to logstash via filebeat.
2. Create `grok` pattern for your log model.
3. Create charts via `kibana` and monitor in real time.

For realtime monitoring:

Try [netdata](https://github.com/firehol/netdata), Its amazing. Please note its not a replacement for nagios or zabbix.

Comment: ELK stands for Elastic Search, Logstash and Kibana

Comment: I didnt quite get that.

Comment: we are using efk: elastic, fluentd and kibana but the main problem here is how to monitor nginx, here monitoring is not only about log file.
In monitoring i need data like req/s, load, workers used(when to increase it), cpu used by nginx and etc

Comment: Req/s is in the logs, anyway, Try netdata for realtime monitoring, it monitors, almost everything about your host.

Answer (score 0):

After some quick research, I found this: [check_nginx_status.pl](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Web-Servers/nginx/check_nginx_status-2Epl/details). I think defining something like:

```
define command {
    command_name     check-nginx
    command_line     $USER1$/check_nginx_status.pl -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -s $ARG1$ -u $ARG2$ $ARG3$ $ARG4$ $ARG5$ $ARG6$
}
```

is probably just what you're looking for.

The -s flag ($ARG1$) would be the hostname of the virtual host

The -u flag ($ARG2$) would be the specific url (/something/status)

And then the rest of the args would be used if you needed to add any additional flags.

Hope this helps!